# Android app that filters Facebook posts containing a given list of words?

Tags: android, facebook, text-processing

These types of extensions/add-ons are a dime a dozen for the web, so it's odd that there seems to be nothing out there for the mobile devices that people tend to prefer browsing Facebook on.

**Required:**

- Must be available for Android
- Must allow you to filter posts on your Facebook newsfeed based on a list of words and/or text strings that you define

**Preferred, but not required:**

- Must work with the official Facebook app rather than just the mobile version of the site